# Objects difference between javascript and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, object

I want to convert a code from JavaScript to C#.
in javascript we can use an object easily as follows, this function returns the indices of the elements that their addition is equal to the target

```
const nums = [1, 5, 6, 7, 10];
const target = 12;
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    let obj = {};
    for (i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        let found = target-nums[i];
        if(obj[found] != null){
            return [obj[found], i]
        }else{
            obj[nums[i]] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

the return of the function will be [1,3] which is an array of the indices of 5,7 (as 5+7 = 12)

So what is a similar way to accomplish this solution in c#?
Is this applicable by using Objects in C#? or even Arrays/Lists/Dictionaries? What is the best way?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a code translation service. Try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us what you have tried and create a [mre].

Comment: Please ignore the code, In my question I didn't ask to convert the code! This is my problem and I said that from the beginning! I included the code to describe my need. I just wanted to know what is a way in C# to do a similar data storing like those very dynamic objects in javascript

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in JavaScript because arrays are secretly objects here.

In C# it will be a little more complicated because you can't enlarge arrays like that.

You can use `List`, but you will have to increase the length and insert `null`s in between.

I suggest using a dictionary because it's similar to JavaScript's object.

```
var nums = new Dictionary<int, int>()  {
  { 0, 1 },
  { 1, 5 },
  { 2, 6 },
  { 3, 7 },
  { 4, 10 }
}
```

Then you can iterate like that:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, int> entry in nums)
{
    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
}
```